# How do I point traffic from a GCE external IP to a secondary internal IP?

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I currently have a GCE instance that is running Jenkins, and I want to be able to access it from the browser.  It's running on an IP address OTHER than the primary internal address Google gives me.  So for example, the primary internal IP is 10.128.0.8, but Jenkins is running at 10.0.1.15:8081.

How do I direct traffic from <EXTERNAL_IP>:8081 to 10.0.1.15:8081 ?

Please note that my Linux skills are shaky and my networking skills are non-existant, so if you can tell me HOW to do whatever it is I need to do, bonus. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1-** First you need to create a [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc?hl=en_GB#firewall_rules) on the current instance's network eg:

```
gcloud beta compute --project=<project-name> firewall-rules create jenkins --description="8081 port jenkins" --target-tags=jenkins --network=<network-name> --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:8081
```

Then you have to add that rule in the instance (selecting the tag created above) eg:

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags <instance-name> --tags jenkins
```

**2-** Other way it's by Cloud Console from [VPC network/Firewall rules](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls) and then add the Firewall Rule Tag on your instance.

[image]

However you should use the [Alias IP Ranges](http://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip) (from this documentation may respond your question + your FR rules created for External IP).

Comment: But this just points to the internal address (in this case, 10.128.0.8), no?

Comment: sorry by my delayed reply, yes it should point to that internal ip, however you should use the Alias IP Ranges (this documentation has to responses your question + your FR rules created for External IP)  ---> https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip

Comment: @J.Rojas would you mind to edit your answer to incorporate the content of your previous comment? With that we can make it as valid.